# cant access a Text object to change the text in a prefab unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I can't change the text on the prefab with a text input.

this is the prefab ---
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6wEA.png

this is the code trying to access the Text ---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Username : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string username = "";
    [SerializeField] private UsernameText UsernameText = null;

    public void Update()
    {
        UsernameText = username;
    }

}
```

sorry about the formating of this question I am only new to StackOverflow

Comment: Why are you using UsernameText? and what accetly is it. You could just use include UnityEngine.UI; and then use private Text usernamtext. Also naming your variable the same as your class can lead to multple problems so please rename it to usernameText atleast. Also are you sure your username variable ever changes to somethign else that is not and empty string?

Comment: ok i have changed those things but i am trying to access a object from a prefab that is not in any scene at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get access to Text Component on your game object in scene https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html.

Try use this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Username : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string username = "";
    [SerializeField] private Text UsernameText = null;

    public void Update()
    {
        UsernameText.text = username;
    }

}
```

Comment: as the prefab is not in any scene's until the multiplayer networking spawns it in

Comment: What are you trying to do? Did you set the UsernameText variable in Editor?